# What is the logic/philosophy of positioning in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am not a web programmer, but we all find ourselves needing to mess around with html, css, and javascript at some point. And every time I do, I find myself hating CSS's guts. This is almost entirely related to positioning. Many things that I think should be easy and straightforward turn out to be very difficult or even (seemingly) impossible.

Take centering something in the user's browser/interface. I recently wanted to do a "Coming Soon…" temporary splash page (cliche, I know), and I wanted a tiny piece of text or image to land right in the middle of the user's browser. Conceptually this couldn't be simpler, and yet to actually achieve this in CSS you have to do all kinds of tricks. I'm not asking **how** you achieve this. There are several tutorials/examples, including these two excellent ones:

http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

http://www.dynamicsitesolutions.com/css/center-page-content-horizontally-and-vertically/

What I want to understand is why it is so complex to achieve something so basic? Why can't I just make a div (or whatever) that spans the height and width of the browser, and align something in the middle of that? Why do you have to come up with entire frameworks like Bootstrap (which, in my opinion, are still incomplete and hacky) to do things that should be a part of the philosophy of the implementation?

The people that come up with the CSS standard are much smarter than I am, and there must be a reason for this. What is their logic or philosophy behind how it is implemented? What am I missing? I want to understand, so at least next time I try to implement something I won't fool myself into thinking "This will be easy" when, I assume, there is a reason it can't be.

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206951/is-there-any-difference-between-using-absolute-position-around-a-relative-positi ???

Comment: Because the html and body elements do not span the entire height of the browser window, but only the content. So, if you have a single line, the body element will only be a single line high (plus padding and margin)

Comment: While I can relate to the validity of your point, this isn't actually a _question_. You seem to specifically ask for opinion based and kind of vague rants about the CSS topic. I'm not sure you should ask this in SO.

Comment: I always thought of it as *"There go my people. I must find out where they are going so I can lead them"*. That isn't a bad strategy, by the way, but it means you can't do *now* what you want to do, but it will become easy some day. For your problem there's [`display: table-cell`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Values). Up next: [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)

Comment: @Joum, I actually agree completely. However, I didn't think it would fit in any of the other StackExchanges, and I'm not sure where else to ask. I prefer not to go to a place like Reddit, as my hit-rate of serious, helpful responses is low there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Because HTML/CSS is limited by its roots: ltr horizontal flow

When we first started making websites, HTML was designed as a simple way to make content flow, like in a magazine or a book. Maybe it would have images or embedded audio, but there was no way to foresee at the time that we would have websites in the millions of lines of code. **HTML was designed with horizontal flow, *not vertical flow* in mind.**

There are other examples of this:

1. It is comparatively difficult to vertically align text to the center or bottom of a page, [this requires a lot of unintuitive understanding](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html) whereas central alignment on the horizontal plane is a simple `text-align='center';`
2. Tables are defined with `<tr>` table row tags, not `<tc>` table column tags.
3. Ever tried making a `<DIV>`, especially one wrapped inside other divs, the full height of the page *(not screen)*? It's not as easy as you'd think.
4. An element with `height:100%` is not automatically the same height as your browser, only the height of your content. [See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/EqkDF/).

Because of the need to maintain backwards compatibility, browsers continue to use rendering engines based on left-to-right, top to bottom rendering. It seems unlikely that an alternative to HTML will take the web by storm any time soon, so we're probably stuck with this paradigm for the foreseeable future.

Comment: You forgot to save your fiddle. Or, you pasted the wrong link.

Comment: Also, `height: 100%` isn't "automatically" "the height of your content". It's *supposed* to be 100% of the height of its parent. The problem is that the parent doesn't have a defined height, so *instead* it computes to `height: auto`, and that causes it to shrink to fit its contents.

Comment: @BoltClock My point exactly, this is another example of HTML being designed for horizontal flow: it doesn't even assume you have the whole browser window for height unless you do a bunch of hacky stuff. Not saying it's difficult, just unintuitive.

Comment: On a more positive note - CSS formatting systems like flexbox may very well open us up to more advanced positioning schemes. But it'll be a long time before any of those technologies enter the mainstream.